# how to initialize IMAPISession OpenMsgStore?

Tags: c++, outlook, mapi

I am using MAPI for tracking the incoming messages. (using C++)
I have called MAPIInitialize and LAPILogonEx as follows:

```
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = MAPIInitialize(0);
    IMAPISession *pSession;
    hr = MAPILogonEx(0, NULL, NULL, 0, (LPMAPISESSION *)&pSession);
```

I want to register this for notifications as I want to track the incoming messages. So I tried to call the `IMAPISession::OpenMsgStore` before calling `IMsgStore::Advise` as follows:

```
   IMsgStore *imsg = NULL;
   hr = pSession->OpenMsgStore(NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &imsg);
```

But the above call does not work (It returns -2147221241). I am passing 0 to the Entry ID because I want to track messages in all the folders. Can someone please help me about where I am going wrong? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is MAPI_E_INVALID_ENTRYID. You cannot pass NULL for the entry id.
You need to call IMAPIsession::GetMsgStoresTables, find the message store that you need, then pass its entry id to OpenMsgStore.